# Pattern matching functions of variables

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I am trying work with a general operator z[] and later plug in candidate forms for z[]. But pattern matching turns the inside z[] into a constant and can no longer perform operations on it:

```
r = z[(x + 2)^2];
r /. z[a_] -> Expand[a]
r /. z[a_] -> Integrate[a, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Results in:

```
(*   (2 + x)^2   *)
(*    10 (2 + x)^2    *)
```

I would like it to return:

4 + 4x + x^2

1720/3

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Change `Rule` ( `->`) to `RuleDelayed` ( `:>`).

Comment: @kguler  Thanks, that fixed it.  Can you tell me now why so many people post good answers in the Comments instead of the Answer slot?  I can Accept it if put it in the Answer slot.

Comment: just posted the comment as an answer. Re "... why ... in the Comments ..", i wasn't sure if it would be a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `Rule` to `RuleDelayed`

```
r = z[(x + 2)^2];
r /. z[a_] :> Expand[a]
(* 4 + 4 x + x^2 *)
r /. z[a_] :> Integrate[a, {x, 0, 10}]
(* 1720/30 *)
```

gives the desired output.

Alternatively, you can use `Rule` to replace the `Head` `z` with the desired function:

```
r = z[(x + 2)^2];
r /. z -> Expand
(* 4 + 4 x + x^2 *)
r /. z -> (Integrate[#, {x, 0, 10}] &)
(* 1720/30 *)
```